# Multi Column Sort in Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, columnsorting

I want to do a Multi-Column sort in Power BI (Consider Column A ad Column B). I want to sort initially with ColumnA and then with Column B. While surfing through the internet I found that after sorting ColumnA, sort ColumnB by pressing the shift key will be the solution. It is not working in my power bi desktop.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where are you trying to sort your data? You can do it in a visual rather than the data engine.

Comment: Sorry, it was a problem with the version of Power BI desktop. And Microsoft helped me to sort it out.